# SOLR Query parameters to avoid flooding with the same manufacturer

Tags: search, solr

I've been a long time browser here, but never have had a question that wasn't already asked. So here goes:

I've run into a problem using SOLR search where some searches on SOLR (let's say DVD Players) tend to return a lot of search results from the same manufacturer in the first 50 results.

Now assuming that I want to provide my end-user with the best experience searching, but also the best variety of products in my catalog, how would I go about providing a type of demerit to reduce the same brand from showing up in the search results more than 5 times. For the record I'm using a fairly standard DisMax search handler.

This logic would only be applied to extremely broad queries like 'DVD Players', or 'Hard Drives', and naturally I wouldn't use it to shape 'Samsung DVD Players' search results.

I don't know if SOLR has a nifty feature that does this automatically, or if I would have to start modifying search handler logic.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve this is a lengthy and complex process but worth trying. Let's say the main field on which you are searching is a single field called title, first you'll need to make sure that all the documents containing "dvd player" in it have same score. This you can do by neglecting     solr scoring parameteres like field norm (set omitNorms=true) &  term frequency (write a solr plugin to neglect it) code attached..

Implementation Details:

1) compile the following class and put it into Solr WEB-INF/classes

---

```
package my.package; 
import org.apache.lucene.search.DefaultSimilarity;

public class CustomSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

public float tf(float freq) {
    return freq > 0 ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}

}
```

---

1. In solrconfig.xml use this new similarity class add

similarity class="my.package.CustomSimilarity"

All this will help you to make score for all the documents with "dvd player" in their title same.  After that you can define one  field of random type. Then when you query solr you can arrange first by score, then by the random field. Since score for all the documents containing DVD players would be same, results will get arranged by random field, giving the customer better variety of products in your catalog.

Comment: Hi Suryansh
This is probably the approach I'm going to have to go with. I'll start working on this, thanks again for your help - Dave

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this but I believe field collapsing / grouping would be what you want.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

If I understand this feature correctly it would group similar results kind of how http://news.google.com/ does it by grouping similar news stories.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I looked into grouping unfortunately it looks like it involves messing with the order of the products (I already have a scoring system that I'd like to keep). I would rather not have the results come back grouped by manufacturer and it doesn't look like there's a way to sort the results regardless of the group (Would kind of defeat the purpose of the group function :) My current product listing page is a grid of products and I'm looking for a nice rich selection of manufacturers to come back based on the category.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas here, although I've not tried them myself.

You can use Carrot plugin for Solr to cluster search results lets say on manufacturer and then feed it to custom RequestHandler to re-order (cherry picking from each mfr. cluster) the result for diversity.

However, there is a downside to the approach that you may need to fetch larger than necessary and secondly the search results will be synthetic.

Comment: Because I don't have a specific list of manufacturers or a specific number of results that I would like to pull from that manufacturer I have a feeling this would be pretty restrictive way of implementing it. I do like the idea of Carrot though for another project I might be working on. Thanks for the tip!